# Maximum number of colors & maximum depth possible

Tags: opencv, colors, color-depth

What is  maximum number of colors possible  for a picture?

What is the maximum depth?

Comment: It may also be worth reviewing the documentation - http://docs.opencv.org/opencv2refman.pdf. For example, for the face detection algorithm, a max of 8-bit color or greyscale is supported.

Comment: There is no limit for that, except for the limit the libraries you use impose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking about an image using the RGB color model.

There are multiple different color depths used - 8-bit (2^24 possible colors, but only 2^8 may be actually used on the image), 16-bit (2^15 or 2^16 possible colors, depending on the implementation in question), 24-bit (2^24 possible colors) and some devices may very well use 48-bit depth (2^48 possible colors).

Today, 24-bit color is considered standard for most image formats, and is commonly expanded into 32-bit ARGB or RGBA.